# Laravel Eloquent Model inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, model, eloquent

I'm a new bit who is trying to build an app using Laravel 5.5, and the Eloquent model.

I have two classes: (1)
**Customer**
and (2)
**VIPCustomer** which extends Customer.

You may immediately tell VIPCustomer contains all attributes that a customer has, and other extra attributes.

Just to be clear, a customer may not be a VIP, and a VIP must be a customer; The customer may immediately opt-in to be a VIP the first time he shops.

Therefore, I am attempting to do something like this in the database:

Customer:

```
+------------------------+
|id|name|gender|join_date|
+------------------------+
```

VIPCustomer:

```
+----------------------------------+
|customer_id|valid_until|type|point|
+----------------------------------+
(customer_id is a foriegn key referencing Customer.id)
```

And accordingly, in the model php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

}
```

.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VIPCustomer extends Customer
{
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

And that's it? I saw there are others saying I should using polymorphic relationship but I don't understand what it means.

In addition, is it possible to do instantiate a new VIP Customer something like this?

```
$customer = new VIPCustomer;
$customer->name   = 'Alice';
$customer->gender = 'F';
$customer->type   = 'gold';
$customer->point  =  0;
$customer->save();
```

On top of that, say when the VIP membership ends, is it possible to preserve that person as **Customer**? Because I'm afraid deleting that person will delete him from both Customer and VIPCustomer tables.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current `VIPCustomer` class looks like a class that holds a VIP data, not a subject (a customer). Then so, I would rename it as `VIPCustomerData` here and make a new `VIPCustomer` to inherit `Customer` class instead.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';
}
```

Make sure you define the table name to avoid it being guessed by inheritance. Then tell `VIPCustomer` to has a relation to `VIPCustomerData`.

```
class VIPCustomer extends Customer
{
    public function vipData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(VIPCustomerData::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is whenever you're going to retrieve VIP customers like `VIPCustomer::get()`, you'll get whole customers instead. So, applying global scope is needed.

```
class VIPCustomer extends Customer
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('weareviptypeofcustomer', function ($q) {
            $q->has('vipData'); // only customers with vip data
        });
    }

    public function vipData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(VIPCustomerData::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

To create a new Customer as VIP, of course 2 queries is needed to insert here. Example,

```
$vipCustomer = new VIPCustomer;
$vipCustomer->name   = 'Alice';
$vipCustomer->gender = 'F';
$vipCustomer->save();

$vipCustomerData = new VIPCustomerData;
$vipCustomerData->type   = 'gold';
$vipCustomerData->point  =  0;

$vipCustomer->vipData()->save($vipCustomerData);
```

Example of updating point.

```
$vipCustomerData = $vipCustomer->vipData; // or $vipCustomer->vipData()->first();
$vipCustomerData->point  =  10;
$vipCustomerData->save();
```

Example of removing VIP status from customer. Of course just delete VIPCustomerData from its table.

```
$vipCustomer->vipData()->delete();
```

---

However, it's better to maintain these subjects as one class if there is no special column to treat each subject differently.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customers';

    protected $with = ['vipData']; // always eager load related 'vipData'

    protected $appends = ['is_vip']; // append 'is_vip' accessor

    public function vipData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(static::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
    }

    public function getIsVipAttribute()
    {
        return (bool) $this->vipData;
    }
}

$customers = Customer::all();

foreach($customers as $customer) {
    if ($customer->is_vip) {
        // is VIP
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very clear. But how do I cast a customer to a VIPCustomer then?

Comment: Glad it helped, you can mark this as answer if you feel it is. You _should not_ cast customer to VIP, as mostly in programming, parent class should never know its children. What they do, doing, are, etc. I gave you more example to just make a property that hold a state to tell whether it's VIP or not.

Comment: It seems that whenever I need to change a customer to a VIP, I need to delete that customer and remember his ID & info, and explicitly set the ID to the new VIP; since I need different controllers for VIP and normal customers as there are features exclusive only for VIP customers. Thank you anyway.